# Is it possible for the python timeit function to ever report 0 as the execution time?

Tags: python, algorithm, insertion-sort, timeit

I'm working on a project in which we have to compare the execution time of several sorting algorithms (insertion sort, quicksort, merge sort,...) for lists of sizes 2 to 2^16. My instructor pointed out that since modern computers are very fast, the runtime for "small" sizes may not register at all and be reported as 0. As a solution, it is recommended that for small instances we run the algorithm in an additional loop and time the total execution, then divide this total time by the number of loop repetitions. For instance,

```
while(repeat test 20 times) 
        while(execute algorithm 50 times)
             run algorithm
```

I'm using the Python timeit function to accomplish this as follows

```
    setup = '''
gc.enable()
import random
from __main__ import insertionSort
from __main__ import n #current instance size
from __main__ import s #random array
    '''
    average = sum(timeit.Timer('A=s[:]; insertionSort(A);',setup = setup).repeat(20,50))/20
```

I do this for sizes of n up to 32, at which point I continue testing by doing

```
average = sum(timeit.Timer('A=s[:]; insertionSort(A);',setup = setup).repeat(1,50))/50
```

The problem that I'm having is that once I go beyond 32, the averages drop down

```
Averages for size 2^ 1
Insertion Sort Average:  0.00014180380003381288
Averages for size 2^ 2
Insertion Sort Average:  0.0002706763001697254
Averages for size 2^ 3
Insertion Sort Average:  0.0005087433502012573
Averages for size 2^ 4
Insertion Sort Average:  0.0018256775000736526
Averages for size 2^ 5
Insertion Sort Average:  0.006701907949900487
Averages for size 2^ 6
Insertion Sort Average:  0.00045550270002422624 #smaller average for larger instance?!
```

So I guess my question is- **is having the extra repetition of smaller instances necessary**? I tried timing single executions of size 2 and got numbers really close to 0 (x10^-6), but never actually got zero.

Comment: By default most `timeit` functions run the code 1,000,000 times. This is why therere is no additional loop needed. BTW You overwrote that with the `50` in the `repeat()` call, to loop only 50 times.

Comment: Yeah I'm only running 50 executions because it takes immense amounts of time to execute each algorithm for huge values of n as it is. This is why I'm asking if I should be doing an extra loop for smaller instances, and also because it doesn't actually appear to ever be 0.

Comment: Do an experiment: run `print(time.time())` several times in a loop. See if you ever get the exact same time. If not, even measuring the timing will result in a number > 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a little experimentation, and it does seem to be necessary -- not for avoiding 0 times, but to amortize some overhead.  This is a typical example, the degenerate case of the **pass** command:

```
>>> for n in range(9):
...   timeit.timeit("pass", number=10**n)/(10**n)
... 
3.0994415283203125e-06
1.9073486328125001e-07
5.0067901611328123e-08
3.6001205444335936e-08
3.3092498779296877e-08
3.4611225128173827e-08
1.6702890396118163e-08
1.2709689140319825e-08
1.1296820640563965e-08
```

This suggests an overhead of ~3 microseconds, and an execution time of ~11 nanoseconds.